# Common baseclass for iterables?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, iterator, tuples

I'm trying to create a method which only accepts an iterable parameter, such as `list`, `tuple`, `set` or `dict`.

Here's my code:

```
class MjmMenuControl(MjmBaseMenu):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        iterables = (dict, list, set, tuple)
        for iterable in iterables:
            if isinstance(items, iterable):
                ...
                break
```

However, I was wondering if there's an easier way, such as `if isinstance(items, <iterable_base_class>):` but I couldn't find anything.

I already tried finding baseclass for `list` etc. but they all seem to derive from `object`:

```
>>> inspect.getmro(list)
(<class 'list'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> inspect.getmro(tuple)
(<class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Is this possible or do I have to stick with the awful `for` loop?

Comment: "if there's an easier way" - yes, omit the type check altogether.

Comment: As a side note, you don't actually need the `for` loop, `isinstance` can take in a tuple as the second parameter such that it returns `True` if the first parameter is an instance of *any* of the classes in the tuple.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, use [`collections.abc.Iterable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable):

```
>>> from collections import abc
>>> isinstance(set(), abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance((), abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance([], abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance('', abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance({}, abc.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance(0, abc.Iterable)
False
```

However, I'd just have the method *assume* it is passed an iterable, it's the responsibility of the *caller* to ensure the correct type is passed in.

The [`collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) is new in Python 3.3; its contents formerly lived in the [`collections` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) instead, albeit that the names are still available in the old location even in Python 3.3 and up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll accept asap :) Can you also explain why it doesn't show in `inspect.getmro()`, I thought it shows all base classes? Also the method accepts any type of parameter but does different things for different types so that's the real reason I need to check whether it's iterable or not. I thought giving an example where my program only accepts an iterable would be easier to understand :)

Comment: `list` and `tuple` are not subclasses here, they are just distinct types that happen to implement the same protocols. *There is no iterable baseclass*.

Comment: If you need to alter behaviour, then testing for `Iterable` can be a good option, yes.

Comment: Ahem, what about Python 2.x?

Comment: @qarma: use [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable).

Comment: @qarma: I note that the Python 3 documentation for the [`collections.abc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) states it was originally part of `collections`; the Python 3 version still has aliases in place too.

Comment: Yes, exatcly what I was looking for. I checked `abc` to no avail, but didn't think to check `collections`. Thanks!

Comment: What is a good pattern to use if you want to distinguish between strings and other Iterables? `if isinstance(foo, str): ... elif isinstance(foo, abc.Iterable):`?

Comment: @Dan: sure, if you need to handle strings separately. Or `isinstancne(foo, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(foo, str)`, etc. It depends on what you are trying to do, really.

Answer (score 5):

One weakness of the `collections.abc.Iterable` option is it can't cope with custom iterable classes like this...

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

class MyIterable(object):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= 10:
            raise IndexError
        return index

>>> myiter = MyIterable()
>>> isinstance(myiter, Iterable)
False
>>> [i for i in myiter]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

It's often claimed that the 'Pythonic' way of doing this is to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), i.e. to try treating the object as an iterable, and handling the exception if it fails. For example...

```
class MjmMenuControl(MjmBaseMenu):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        try:
            for item in items:
                do_something_with(item)
        except TypeError:
            # If we get here, 'items' is not iterable
            do_something_else()
```

...however, both methods have the weakness of treating strings to be the same thing as, say, lists, which isn't usually what you want. Usually you want to test for an iterable **container**, which is slightly different, so it's common to see code which treats strings as a special case like this...

```
class MjmMenuControl(MjmBaseMenu):
    def __init__(self, items=None):
        if isinstance(items, (str, bytes)):
            do_something_else()
        else:
            try:
                for item in items:
                    do_something_with(item)
            except TypeError:
                # If we get here, 'items' is not iterable
                do_something_else()
```

...which is a little messy, but gets the job done.

Comment: I've changed `basestring` to `(str, bytes)` since the question is tagged python-3.x, where they no longer have a common subclass (aside from `object`).

Comment: You should be using `__iter__` instead of `__getitem__` *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Probably should, but the point about duck typing still stands. I recall having a long argument with a certain Tim Peters about this point. He kept stressing the point that Python is not about 'inheritance', but 'interfaces', because it allows you to write functions which are more tolerant of their argument types. I didn't agree with him at the time, but it makes more sense to me now. :)

Comment: Oh, I know Tim Peters, I used to work with him. ABCs are *all about* interfaces. ABCs test for methods, not subclasses. If your `MyIterable` class was *really* an iterable (so you could call `iter()` on it), then it'll test True against the `Iterable` ABC too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like you're right. Perhaps the `_abcoll.py` also ought to check for the presence of the `__getitem__` attribute? Seems odd that it's possible to create objects which are iterable in the Python language (in the sense that you can do `for item in myobject`), which aren't picked up as `Iterable`.

Comment: No, `__getitem__` implies other types; see the `Sequence` ABC, for example, but also the `Mapping` ABC. `__getitem__` support is there for old-style types really, `__iter__` is a more recent addition that your newer code really should use instead.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't picked up on the minor distinction between `Sequence` and `Iterable`, although they are kind of similar. It's possible that what the OP is really after is the former, not the latter. TBH, I started with Python about 15 years ago, and I haven't really had time to keep up with all the new features. I shall have to investigate further. :)